# Create Bar chart for array of nested objects in Kibana with Vega

Tags: elasticsearch, charts, kibana, vega

i have problem in drawing chart for my data with Vega in kibana
my data is like this

```
{
    "took": 10,
    "timed_out": false,
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "request_index",
                "_id": "eaae227e-cf8f-411d-a8b3-0d66595d8730",
                "_source": {
                    "creationDate": "2021-12-04T13:03:13.186Z",
                    "requests": [
                        {
                            "searchEngine": "Google",
                            "execTime": 235
                        },
                        {
                            "searchEngine": "Bing",
                            "execTime": 952
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "request_index",
                "_id": "ac03a6de-23af-4e2d-9315-a36a82ffd251",
                "_source": {
                    "creationDate": "2021-11-04T13:03:13.186Z",
                    "requests": [
                        {
                            "searchEngine": "Yahoo",
                            "execTime": 75
                        },
                        {
                            "searchEngine": "Google",
                            "execTime": 145
                        },
                        {
                            "searchEngine": "Bing",
                            "execTime": 170
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to draw bar chart for average of execTime per searchEngine like this
[example chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi83H.png)

and also historical average for execTime and split charts by searchEngine

can anyone help me?

Comment: You want to use a flatten and project transform. Flatten will squash the array objects into per line documents, and project will allows you to jump to the array fields to flatten them. After that you will want to aggregate transform to group the data by searchEngine.